# e1071 svm queries regarding plot and tune

Tags: r, data-visualization, svm, e1071

I am new to R and I am learning the e1071 packages' svm function.

Following are the few questions I have.

1. How does the plot function work?

I cannot understand the plotting case with more than 2 factors in the class variable. Like in the line below, why `Petal.Width` and `Petal.Length` are chosen as the two dimensions for plotting and how other dimensions affect the result? Moreover, I am also not clear with the slice parameter, what is it and why the values 3 and 4 are set?

```
plot(model,iris, Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, slice= list(Sepal.Width=3,Sepal.Length=4))
```

2. What is the tune function and how we choose the gamma and cost variables as shown in this example in the cran documentation.

obj <- tune.svm(Species~., data = iris, gamma = 2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the plot function of e1071 but I can help with your second question.

The purpose of the `tune` function is to find the optimal cost and gamma parameters, where by optimal we mean producing the smallest test error rate. In this case the selection is done by a grid search wherein the user supplies a series of values for each tuning parameter and the function estimates the test error rate for each possible combination. In the example above, there are 3 possible gammas and 3 possible costs meaning that there are 9 different combinations of cost and gamma for which the test error rate is to be evaluated. The evaluation of the test error rate is done by k-fold cross validation, with 10 folds being the default.
As for what values to provide the `tune` function, typically one starts with a wide range and then hones in. For example, it is not uncommon to start with $log_{10}$ scale values such as `cost = 10^(0:4), gamma = 10^(-4:-1)`. They happen to have used $log_2$ scale values in the example.